# I want to add three years in dropdown list dynamically using javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to add three years in dropdown list dynamically using javascript.

For example: If I add '2014,2015,2016' in dropdown list then these years should switch every year i.e. if current year is 2017 and if 2017 ends and 2018 started then on 1 JANUARY 2018, year 2014 should drop and under 2016 in dropdown list 2017 gets added and years dropdown list should change from 
'2014,2015,2016' to '2015,2016,2017'. This list should change every year.
Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your HTML:

```
<select id="years">
</select>
```

This is your script, that will always update the combobox:

```
function populateCombo() {
    var today = new Date();
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
    var select = document.getElementById("years"); 

    for(var i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        var opt = yyyy-i;
        var el = document.createElement("option");
        el.textContent = opt;
        el.value = opt;
        select.appendChild(el);
        }
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/L7hzgom2/

Comment: Hi Fabio Can you please help me how to use this function in XML to populate dynamic values in dropdown?

Comment: I am not expert of XML. You asked for javascript, and that's what I did.